# Using MySQL Join

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join two MySQL Tables to get a staffid from one and a username that is tied to the staffid in another table so that I just have the username displayed

```
SELECT ost_ticket.staff_id, count(*) as numbers 
FROM ost_ticket AS us
JOIN ost_staff AS re
ON re.username = us.userid
GROUP BY ost_ticket.staff_id;
```

From what I've been reading about joins this should work?

EDIT:  I've ran it and I get unknown column 'ost_ticket.staff_id' in field list

Comment: Have you ran the query yet?? Thats the best way to find out if it worked

Comment: What issue did you encounter? Consider explaining what you expect to happen, what you tried, and how that attempt failed. For best results, create an SQL Fiddle with an example.

Comment: Sorry, yes I've ran it and I get unknown column 'ost_ticket.staff_id' in field list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT us.staff_id, re.username, count(*) as numbers 
FROM ost_ticket AS us
JOIN ost_staff AS re
ON re.userid= us.staff_id
GROUP BY us.staff_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You've aliased the two tables (as `re` and `us`), so you'll need to use the aliases. Also, it seems you've joined to the `ost_staff` table to retrieve the username, so if you want to display the user name, you need to select + group by it, and not the `staff_id` column.

```
SELECT re.username, count(*) as numbers 
FROM ost_ticket AS us
JOIN ost_staff AS re
ON re.userid = us.userid
GROUP BY re.username;
```

(substitute your actual PK for `ost_staff` - I've assumed `userid`)